# Python: Changes to another module's variable not reflected

Tags: python, import, module, scope, package

Please explain the output?

```
                           # maindir/config/config.py                    
foo = 0
```

```
                           # maindir/worker/worker.py                    
import maindir.config.config

def print_foo():
    print maindir.config.config.foo
```

```
                           # maindir/main.py                    
import config.config
import worker.worker

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print config.config.foo
    config.config.foo = 5
    print config.config.foo
    worker.worker.print_foo()
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
$ env PYTHONPATH=. python maindir/main.py
0
5
0                          # was expecting 5 ...
```

On the other hand if we switch to `import config.config` in `worker.py`, then there is no surprise:

```
                           # maindir/worker/worker.py                    
import config.config

def print_foo():
    print config.config.foo
```

OUTPUT:

```
$ env PYTHONPATH=./maindir python maindir/main.py
0
5
5
```